What is the name for introducing new justifications when the original justifications are disproved?
I am asking about whether there is a general principle in law in cases such as the following. If there is, what is its name.
An employer is entitled to dismiss an employee for a number of possible reasons, and the employee is entitled to appeal (in the UK this would be to an Industrial Tribunal). The employer dismisses the employee for being frequently late. On appeal the employer accepts, or the employee proves, that in fact he has not been late at all. Ordinarily in that case the employee is entitled to be reinstated.
However, at that stage, during the tribunal, the employer states that the employee has stolen a sheet of toilet paper and that the employer was therefore justified in dismissing the employee after all.
Another example might be where a landlord evicts a tenant claiming that there have been complaints from the neighbours about the noise. The tenant subsequently appeals and proves there had, in fact, been no complaints. However the landlord then mentions something else, not previously mentioned, that the tenant kept a cat, contrary to the agreement.
Both these cases involve 1) someone taking action based on one justification; 2) that justification being shown to be false; and 3) the person subsequently seeking to justify the action on a different ground.
My questions are

Is there a name for this concept of introducing a new alleged justification when the original one is disproved?

Is there a general concept that it is acceptable or unacceptable?


(Please don't tell me about whether keeping a cat or stealing toilet paper are valid reasons in themselves. Also, my question is premised on the situation where action can only be taken with justification. So it obviously is not relevant to situations where a contract can be terminated at will.)

This is a very common fact pattern in employment-discrimination law. We most often refer to it simply as "shifting explanations," which is a generally accepted method of proving that all the explanations are actually a pretext for some unlawful discrimination. Cullen v. Select Med. Corp., No. 18-2912, 2-3 (3d Cir. Aug. 22, 2019) (“Its explanation for his firing shifted over time. Thus, Select Medical's explanation may have been pretextual and a jury should have been permitted to consider whether Cullen's firing was retaliatory.”).

There is no term of art, but this has been called "trial by ambush."
In civil litigation, parties to a case need to know the case they must meet. This accomplished by "pleadings": the initiating document by the plaintiff and the responding document by the defendant setting out all the facts they will aim to establish during any eventual adjudication, as well as the legal bases on which they will rely.
E.g. Tutt v. Ishakis, 2020 ONSC 5711:

The "just determination of a civil proceeding on its merits requires a fair adjudicative process. Trial by ambush is not fair. Accordingly, trial unfairness may result where a defendant is permitted to rely on an unpleaded defence which, if pleaded, might have prompted counsel to employ different tactics at trial." Where a defence to a civil action is not pleaded and no pleadings amendment is obtained, judges should generally resist the inclination to allow a defendant to raise and rely on the unpleaded defence if trial fairness and the avoidance of prejudice to the plaintiff are to be achieved.

This rule may be relaxed in administrative tribunals.1 And the remedy may in any case simply be to allow an adjournment, more time, or additional submissions in order to undo any prejudice of the surprise.
Of course, when the statutory scheme requires the justification to have been provided in notice at the time of the action under review (e.g. in some jurisdictions, the eviction notice itself must state the justification), then any alternative justification is simply irrelevant.

1. Here, I refer to the practice in Canada of granting to administrative tribunals the flexibility to design their own procedures within the limits of procedural fairness, and expressly relaxed rules of evidence.

An administrative tribunal does not usually have the discretion that a court has to allow for procedural mistakes to be remedied. That is, it is far more likely that a tribunal will simply have to disallow any argument about matters that weren’t pleaded.
